# jpa repository websocket @MessageMapping

Tags: spring-websocket

I found out, that spring does not create a transaction for websocket requests that are going to a action annotated with @MessageMapping. Even if i annotate the action as @Transactional nothing happens.

I also tried the way with an action that is @RequestMapping annotated. This works as usual.

Has someone an idea how i can make this work? How to make an websocket request transactional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by my self:
I just had to rename my entity manager factory to entityManagerFactory... Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You shoould show your code, because it really works, unless you have some `async` internal logic, which doesn fit for single-threaded transactional boundries.

Comment: Hey, 
i created an example project! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtfdgKReCxqMlB0MzJaZ0lObmc/edit?usp=sharing
You can just start it via StartServer.java. If you go then to localhost:8080/test2 an test entity is stored and if you go to localhost:8080/test.html and send a message an exception gets thrown because no transaction is available