# Spring Boot+WebSocket+Stomp+JPA: data not inserted even with @Transactional annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a RestController which contains two method:

1. method `beat1` with @MessageMapping annotation to receive the websocket message (in `STOMP` protocol) from client
2. method `beat2` with @RequestMapping annotation to receive HTTP request from client

The two methods have the same code inside:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/member")
@MessageMapping("member")
public class MemberCtrl
{
  @MessageMapping("beat")
  public Heartbeat beat1(@Payload Heartbeat heartbeat)
  {
    return memberService.beat(heartbeat);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/beat", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Heartbeat beat2(@RequestBody Heartbeat heartbeat)
  {
    return memberService.beat(heartbeat);
  }
}
```

The `memberService` is just a normal Spring service that contains the business logic which will do a database data insertion with Spring `JPARepository`:

```
@Service
public class MemberServiceImpl implements MemberService, UserDetailsService
{

    @Autowired
    private HeartbeatRepository heartbeatRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Heartbeat beat(Heartbeat heartbeat)
    {
        heartbeat = heartbeatRepository.save(heartbeat);
        return heartbeat;
    }
}
```

As for the code of my `HeartbeatRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface HeatbeatRepository extends JpaRepository<Heartbeat, Integer>
{

}
```

Here's my problem:

1. When I send a STOMP message with websocket, the `beat1` method in the controller do execute, however, no data was inserted into DB table.
2. When I send a http request, the `beat2` method in controller is executed, and the Heartbeat domain object was successfully inserted into DB table.

I'm implementing websocket, so what I need is to get `beat1` works, I actually don't need `beat2` at all. (`beat2` is just for testing)

Since both `beat1` and `beat2` method are calling the same Service method in `memberSevice`, and `beat2` works, I think my implementation of `MemberService` and `HeartbeatRepository` have no problem.

As fot the hibernate's log for each of `beat1` and `beat2`,

1. `baat1` only print the SQL for getting next id, and I didn't see the SQL for insertion and transaction commit:

   ```
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.227 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('heartbeat_id_seq')
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.227 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Obtaining JDBC connection
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.242 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Obtained JDBC connection
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.261 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator       : Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Integer[20]]
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.261 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 20, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.266 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Releasing JDBC connection
   2016-08-23 18:32:56.266 DEBUG 43874 --- [nboundChannel-4] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Released JDBC connection
   ```

2.`beat2` do print the completed insetaion SQL and commit the transaction, so that's why it succeed to do the insertion to DB table:

```
2016-08-23 18:20:29.937 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl      : begin
2016-08-23 18:20:29.937 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Obtaining JDBC connection
2016-08-23 18:20:29.951 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Obtained JDBC connection
2016-08-23 18:20:29.951 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : initial autocommit status: true
2016-08-23 18:20:29.951 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : disabling autocommit
2016-08-23 18:20:29.966 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('heartbeat_id_seq')
2016-08-23 18:20:29.986 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator       : Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Integer[19]]
2016-08-23 18:20:29.986 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 19, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
2016-08-23 18:20:29.992 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl      : committing
2016-08-23 18:20:29.993 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2016-08-23 18:20:29.993 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2016-08-23 18:20:29.995 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2016-08-23 18:20:29.995 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2016-08-23 18:20:29.996 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2016-08-23 18:20:29.998 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.yamk.api.domain.orm.Heartbeat{lifespanSec=0, lostedSec=0, lastHeartbeatTime=Tue Aug 23 18:19:35 UTC 2016, createdTime=Tue Aug 23 18:20:29 UTC 2016, location=POINT (121.56818389892578 25.033194472364688), id=19}
2016-08-23 18:20:30.006 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into heartbeat (created_time, last_heartbeat_time, lifespan_sec, location, losted_sec, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into heartbeat (created_time, last_heartbeat_time, lifespan_sec, location, losted_sec, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2016-08-23 18:20:30.088 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : committed JDBC Connection
2016-08-23 18:20:30.088 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.t.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction    : re-enabling autocommit
2016-08-23 18:20:30.091 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [com.yamk.api.domain.orm.Heartbeat@32] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@69f8302c]
2016-08-23 18:20:30.091 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-08-23 18:20:30.091 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2016-08-23 18:20:30.091 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Releasing JDBC connection
2016-08-23 18:20:30.091 DEBUG 43846 --- [nio-8989-exec-9] o.h.e.j.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl   : Released JDBC connection
```

**So what's the problem with my code that causing such a different outcome on `beat1` (WebSocket) and `beat2` (HTTP Request) ?**

It seems that Spring does not automatically give me a transaction even if `@Transactional` annotation is used when MessageMapping method `beat1` is called and that is wierd.

Comment: I acutally found a very similar problem at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082234/jpa-repository-websocket-messagemapping). However, the solution does not make sense for my situation because I am using auto-configuration using `application.properties` file to configurate database connection, JPA, and Hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself.
It turns out that I have to manually configurate `PlatformTransactionManager` using `@Bean` and using `JpaTransactionManager` as the implementation:

```
    @ComponentScan
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @EnableCaching
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class App
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
      }

      @Autowired
      private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

      @Bean
      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() 
      {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }

    }
```

That's all, then everything works.

But I still don't understand why Spring Boot didn't auto-configurate the PlatformTransactionManager using my `applicaion.properites` file.
Maybe I misunderstood something or missed something in `application.properites` , here's how my `applicaion.properties` looks like:

```
    # data source
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:####/xxxx
    spring.datasource.username=my-user-name
    spring.datasource.password=my-password
    spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true

    # jpa / hibernate
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:validate
    spring.jpa.show-sql:true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Comment: Changing from DataSourceTransactionManager (legacy code) to JpaTransactionManager made it work, thanks for your solution !